# How to enter a formula in a cell using vba

Tags: excel, vba, formula

I have a formula and I want to enter that formula in all the cells in column B, how can I do that , I have tried various tricks but nothing seems to work.

This is the formula,

```
=MID(A1,SEARCH(":",A1,SEARCH("Assignee Group:",A1))+2,IFERROR(FIND(CHAR(10),A1,SEARCH("Assignee Group:",A1)),LEN(A1))-SEARCH(":",A1,SEARCH("Assignee Group:",A1))-1)
```

It gives me a syntax error every time.

Comment: All `"` need to be doubled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to double up quotes within a quoted string.

```
Option Explicit

Sub wqewre()
    With Worksheets("sheet1")
        With .Range(.Cells(1, "B"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1))
            .Formula = "=MID(A1, SEARCH("":"", A1, SEARCH(""Assignee Group:"", A1))+2, " & _
                         "IFERROR(FIND(CHAR(10), A1, SEARCH(""Assignee Group:"", A1)), " & _
                         "LEN(A1))-SEARCH("":"", A1, SEARCH(""Assignee Group:"", A1))-1)"
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```